# Error parsing xml code using xml.etree in Python

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to learn the basics of XML processing (with lxml) running Python 2.7.2. I've created a REALLY simple starting file, but it's cratering. The code is:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('/Desktop/plc_dmt.xml')

print doc
```

I've tried variations on this code, using different xml files, and also opening the file first before executing the etree.parse() method, but they all yield a similar or identical error message, below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XMLparse_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    doc = etree.parse('/Users/Dad/Desktop/plc_dmt.xml')
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2954, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:56220)
 ...   {Misc  error stuff}
 ... 
  lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlParsePI : no target name, line 3, column 14
```

I confirmed that at least some of the XML files were well-formed, at least insofar as they ran correctly on a web server. I don't understand the error message -- What is the target name it is seeking?

Here's the input xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
<heartbeat><?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 0 ), InReadUByte( 1 ))'-->    </heartbeat>

<dmt node="1">
    <address><?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X", InReadUByte( 20 ))'--></address>
    <status><?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X", InReadUByte( 21 ))'--></status>
    <realflow><?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "%f", InReadFloat( 22 ))'--></realflow>
    <pressure><?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 26 ), InReadUByte( 27 ))'--></pressure>
    <temp><?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 28 ), InReadUByte( 29 ))'--></temp>
</dmt>
# Misc stuff pulled out to keep file shorter...
</response>
```

Much of the embedded code are Server Side Include commands for this web server, which is connected to some instrumentation. This file does operate correctly on the server.

Comment: Post xml please.  We need to see it

Comment: @Just another dunce: I have added an excerpt to the original post, above.

Comment: Passing your XML to http://www.xmlvalidation.com indicates it is not valid XML. On line 3, column 14, "The processing instruction must begin with the name of the target."

Comment: What happens if you call `etree.parse('http://...')` where `http://...` is the URL of the file on the server?

Comment: @unutbu: Thanks for this, I'll check out both ideas. I've never heard of xmlvalidation.com (I'm a noob), that's very interesting. I'll also try the parse on url suggestion, too, just for fun.

Comment: @unutbu: The parse on url approach worked well, and I will move forward using that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is invalid because you have `<` and `>` characters inside your elements. They have to be escaped.

If they were actually supposed to be comments, this is what it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
<heartbeat><!--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 0 ), InReadUByte( 1 ))'-->    </heartbeat>

<dmt node="1">
    <address><!--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X", InReadUByte( 20 ))'--></address>
    <status><!--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X", InReadUByte( 21 ))'--></status>
    <realflow><!--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "%f", InReadFloat( 22 ))'--></realflow>
    <pressure><!--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 26 ), InReadUByte( 27 ))'--></pressure>
    <temp><!--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 28 ), InReadUByte( 29 ))'--></temp>
</dmt>
</response>
```

If that was actually supposed to be text, then they need to be escaped, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
<heartbeat>&lt;?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 0 ), InReadUByte( 1 ))'--&gt;    </heartbeat>

<dmt node="1">
    <address>&lt;?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X", InReadUByte( 20 ))'--&gt;</address>
    <status>&lt;?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X", InReadUByte( 21 ))'--&gt;</status>
    <realflow>&lt;?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "%f", InReadFloat( 22 ))'--&gt;</realflow>
    <pressure>&lt;?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 26 ), InReadUByte( 27 ))'--&gt;</pressure>
    <temp>&lt;?--#exec cmd_argument='printf( "0x%02X%02X", InReadUByte( 28 ), InReadUByte( 29 ))'--&gt;</temp>
</dmt>
</response>
```

The above two documents are both valid.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting, as the Server Side Include commands embedded in the xml have very specific formatting requirements. I'll dive into that deeper and record the results back here.

Comment: [apache ssi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html)? if so, it should be ``!`` not ``?``

Comment: Actually, I don't know which SSI flavor is used, this is a vendor specific device designed to connect to their own chemical process instrumentation, it's not a "general-purpose" server. The docs explicitly state `?`, though, not `!`. I tweaked a code sample using your second suggestion, used the xmlvalidation.com site suggested by @unutbu to confirm a well-formed document, and the lxml.etree code sample didn't throw an exception, but added an extra `&gt;` to the output when I used `tostring`. One thing I still want to check is to actually run the tweaked code on the SSI server.

Comment: Interesting problem: The 'well-formed' code does NOT execute on the server. The original code, which does NOT validate, does operate correctly. I've flagged this issue with the vendor.